# strategy to run Grunt in Docker

Tags: docker, gruntjs, docker-compose, devops

We're developing an application for which I've setup three docker containers (`web`, `db` and `build`) which we run with docker-compose.

I've configured docker so that the hosts folder (`html`) is shared as a writeable folder to `web` and `build`.

Inside the `build` container runs a Grunt watch task as a user `node` which has the uid `1000`.

As the Grunt tasks regulary builds CSS and JavaScript files, these files belong to the user `1000`. As our whole team uses these setup to develop, the files for every team mate belong to another ("random") user, the  user which has the uid `1000`.

What would be the best strategy to avoid this problem? I could think of running the Grunt task with the userid of the hosts user, which started the container. But how to accomplish that?

I should mention, that we don't need those generated files for the version control. So it would be okay when the generated files are local to the docker container. But as the locations in which these files are generated are spread across the whole application, I don't have an idea how I could solve the problem with a read-only volume.